# Where should form action/URL be defined when using jQuery Validate plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Where should form action be defined when using jQuery Validate plugin?

In the JavaScript?

Or in the form?

Or both?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>
        //Links to script go here...  
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                var validator=$("#myForm").validate({
                    rules: {},
                    messages: {},
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        $.post('some/url/to/post/to.php',$(form).serializeArray(),function (json){
                        //Or maybe use form.action as url?  Gives full URL: http://subdomain.example.com/some/url/to/post/to.php
                        //Or maybe use $(form).attr('action') as url?  Gives partial URL: some/url/to/post/to.php
                            //bla bla bla
                            },'json'); 
                    }
                });                
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="myForm" action="some/url/to/post/to.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="bla">
            <input type="submit" value="sumbit">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where should form action be defined when using jQuery Validate plugin?

That depends entirely on how you are going to submit the form.

**1.  Regular form submit, where it's redirected to another page:**

Simply use the `action` attribute within the `form` tag and you would not need to use a custom `submitHandler` option.  The plugin takes care of everything automatically, and after validation, the form submits normally.

**2.  Submit via ajax, where it stays on the same page:**

Simply define the ajax within a custom `submitHandler` function and you would not even need to use the `action` attribute as it will be ignored anyway.  The plugin takes care of everything automatically and will fire the custom `submitHandler` function when the form is valid and the button is clicked.  *(Note:  retrieving the value of the `action` attribute for the ajax to use would not be a problem.)*

Comment: I've since changed the url in the `submitHandler` to use `$(form).attr('action')`, and it works find.  Wouldn't it be best to always do it this way since it would be easier to fall back for non-JS users?

Comment: @user1032531, you're using ajax but retrieving the URL from the form `action` attribute?  I see no problem with this and it certainly falls within my #2 scenario above.

Comment: Thank you Sparky,  Have a great Labor Day!